# How to set the context of the `this` inside a then callback on a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, this

When I call `resolve()` on a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), the scope which the function inside the then() is binded to `window`.

There's any way to set the context of the this like using the [Function.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method?

```js
function Point(){
  var that = this;
  
  var _x = 0;
  
  this.setX = function(x){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            _x = x;
            resolve.apply(that); //<== set this
        }, 1000);
    });
  }

  this.getX = function(){
    return _x;
  }
}

var p = new Point();
p.setX(10).then(function(){
  console.log(this.getX()); //this === `window`
});
```

EDIT:

Elaborating, with synchronous code you can do method chaining, by simply returning the same object over and over.

```
//this pattern
obj.method1();
obj.method2();
...


//becomes this pattern
obj.method1(10).method2(11) ...
```

Implementation of chaining

```
method1 = function(x){
    return this;
}
```

When it comes to assync, you can still do the same thing with callbacks

```
obj.method1(10, function(){ this.method2(11, function(){ ...
```

Implementation with callbacks

```
method1 = function(x, cb){
    cb.apply(this);
}
```

I don't get it why would someone bind the"receiver" function to window, it doesn't make sense to me, as promises are supposed to be analogous to synchronous calls.

Comment: Why would the emitter of the Promise know or worry about the context of the next callback function? This is not something you can or should do. You're trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: It's called "(`this`) context" or "receiver", not "(variable) scope". And no, you cannot set it.

Comment: Just use `p` instead of `this`.

Comment: Return your variable or scope from inside the promise, and the parameter will go to your next `.then()`

Comment: @deceze because promises are supposed to be analogous to synchronous calls. And with synchronous calls you can do method chaining by returning this. This is like in the middle of a function your context becomes window after some random expression call.

Comment: Promises don't promise (pun accidental) to be exactly analogous to synchronous calls, and most certainly not to method chaining. The most they do is allow you to wrangle your asynchronous callbacks *in a more synchronous-like manner*.

Comment: Note that promise chaining work by returning `this` but it's not your object's `this`. Remember `Promise()` is a constructor thus promises are object thus `.then()` chaining work by returning the promise's `this`.

Answer (score 3):

## Option 1:

You can pass the instance into the resolve function. Then reference it via the callback as the first argument.

```js
function Point() {
  var that = this;

  var _x = 0;

  this.setX = function(x) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        _x = x;
        resolve(that); //<== set this
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  this.getX = function() {
    return _x;
  }
}

var p = new Point();
p.setX(10).then(function(scope) {
  console.log(scope.getX());
});
```

## Option 2:

You can bind the scope of the callback:

```
var p = new Point();
p.setX(10).then(function () {
    console.log(this.getX()); //this === `window`
}.bind(p)); // bind the scope here
```

```js
function Point() {
  var that = this;

  var _x = 0;

  this.setX = function(x) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        _x = x;
        resolve.apply(that); //<== set this
      }, 1000);
    });
  };

  this.getX = function() {
    return _x;
  }
}

var p = new Point();
p.setX(10).then(function() {
  console.log(this.getX()); //this === instance of Point
}.bind(p));
```